# Injective linear endomorphism of hilbert space is bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Is it true that an injective continuous endomorphism of a hilbert space is bijective? If not, are there conditions that imply this?

I know this would follow from the rank nullity theorem in finite dimension, but I don't know how to generalize.

Comment: I'll give you a simple counterexample of your first question.  Take the first integral mapping smooth functions to smooth functions that are zero at the origin.  $f(x) \mapsto \int_0^x f(y)dy$.  That is not surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No -- for example, the shift-right map
$$ (x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots) \mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots) $$
is a linear map $\ell^2\to\ell^2$ which preserves the inner product (and so is continuous and injective) but is clearly not surjective.

I'm not aware of any nontrivial sufficient condition that will ensure that such a map is bijective.